# RD published apps not connecting to remote instance

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

I have configured RD components in one single server (for my poc) and I have done configuring 2 machines as session host. I have created a collection and in that RDP for a machine is published.

When I try to connect to that instance using this published app through web access, I am recieveing an error "This computer cant connect to the remote computer".

But I can very well say that I can take rdp to that machine from RD server.Can anyone support me where I am going wrong?

Update: When I connect with my published remote app, it shows as given below:

[image]

Please note that it shows the same server for both target server and gateway server though this is an app published from another remote server. Is this an issue that I am not able to connect to that instance.? Any solution for this?

**Update:** Whenever I try to access remote server through published remote desktop app, it says "this computer cant connect to the remote computer." In such case I can see "error 1296: Remote Desktop Connection Broker Client failed while getting redirection packet from Connection Broker" in remote desktop gateway server event log.

As per microsoft it is an issue between remote desktop connection broker and the target server, but I can ping and reach the RDCB server from the target computer. Any other solutions or suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried adding the server to the group policy as mentioned in https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42318299-2fd0-48db-be5a-77e6922cc36d/sessionbroker-1306-1296-802-errors?forum=winserverTS "Added the connection broker to DC Group policy:  Local Computer Policy>Administrative Templates>Windows Components>Remote Desktop Services >Remote Desktop Session Host> RD Connection Broker >Configure RD Connection Broker server name"

Comment: Another thing to try if you haven't already:  "If you edit the properties of your Session Collection, click on the Security on the left.  There is a setting for Security Layer.  By default it is Negotiate.  If you set it to RDP Security Layer, that is what fixed it for me."  http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/438810-server-2012-rds-connection-from-windows-7-8

Comment: @TonyHinkle: Have mentioned that it is an AWS instance and by default the environment won't be having group policies applied. Though I have tried changing the local security policy earlier itself, but didnt work.. :(

And for the second point, it doesnt work for me.. Really I feel like I am stuck up... with no one to help.. :(

Comment: Few things spring to mind - ensure that if you use RD Gateway the address for the gateway is setup correctly in the app. Furthermore ensure that the Remote Computer field is the same as the "publishing server". Also check that if you use RD Gateway that you have relevant Resource Authorization Policy in place.